Переименовать имя устройства, которое отображается в Телеграм
Здесь среди ответов есть вот это:
Телеграмм берёт это значение из
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS
Параметр SystemProductName
Но проблема в том, что меняю значение SystemProductName, но после перезагрузки компьютера, возвращается прежнее значение.
Как сохранить новое?

Ну так "BIOS" как бы намекает, что оно берется из таблицы SMBIOS, прошитой в ПЗУ. Зачем может понадобится ее менять, тем более ради Телеграм?

Функционал изоляции приложения от системной части реализована различными производителями. В частности, есть технология portable.

а можно как-то изменить то, что записано в  таблице SMBIOS?
